# Matlab power spectrum analysis

Tags: matlab, plot, spectrum, frequency-analysis

I would like to reproduce this image, but with my own EEG data.
For what I understand, it is a power spectrum analysis done on filtered data.

[image: single-sided amplitude spectrum after filtering]

I recorded the EEG signal with a sampling rate of 1000Hz, with DC amplifiers (Low: DC; High:200). My *Data* is: 68 (electrodes) x 185080 (data points).

I have tried to use the following code from:http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/psd-estimate-using-fft.html

```
 Fs = 1000;
 t = 0:1/Fs:1-1/Fs;
 x = Data;
 %x = cos(2*pi*100*t) + randn(size(t));

 N = length(x);
 xdft = fft(x);
 xdft = xdft(1:N/2+1);
 psdx = (1/(Fs*N)) * abs(xdft).^2;
 psdx(2:end-1) = 2*psdx(2:end-1);
 freq = 0:Fs/length(x):Fs/2;
 plot(freq,10*log10(psdx))
 grid on
 title('Periodogram Using FFT')
 xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
 ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')
```

but this is what I obtain:

[image: Periodogram using FFT]

I am struggling understanding how to proceed in order to obtain an analysis of my EEG signal as in the first image. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @willpower2727 the link is the one I used to take the code from.

Comment: Do you have the DSP toolbox?

Comment: @willpower2727 No, I don't have it.

Comment: without thinking too much about the code, your result seems to show just a bunch of noise - i.e. Did you record your EEG signal properly? Even without converting the FFT into a power Spectrum (which btw is very easy and is simply doing some operations on your FFT, the general shape should look the same), you results do not look right, and that has nothing to do with the code. Can you confirm that your input is correct?

Comment: @GameOfThrows Yes, I think I did record the EEG signal properly. This is from a resting state of few minutes. However, I noticed that the electrodes are 68 (including EKG and EMG) which I actually did not use.

Comment: I'm not sure what your inputs are, but your FFT just look like noise - your code seems to be okay though.

Comment: But how do I obtain the first image? I mean, also from the link I used <http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/psd-estimate-using-fft.html> they don't obtain the same type of analysis as in the first image. I assume I need to add some line of codes in order to get that type of analysis where I show the line noise; but not sure which code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to do PSD using fft from scratch and without the DSP toolbox:

```
%this does not include any filtering

x = [0:0.01:pi];
y = sin(100*x);
nfft = 2^nextpow2(length(y));
Fs = 100;

psd1 = abs(fft(y,nfft)).^2/length(y)/Fs;%compute the PSD and normalize

plot([0:50/(length(psd1)/2):50],psd1(1:length(psd1)/2+1))
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('PSD');
grid on
title('PSD from FFT');
```

The result:

[image]

If this method results in a similar one to what you posted then I think the other's comments about your data having some issues may be valid.

Comment: Good question, my variable "x" is like time but it is really only there to build "y" which is analogous to your "Data" variable.

Comment: I only use x to build y, y is where Data goes

Comment: If I use *Data* instead of *y* an error appears: `Error using fft
Requested 262144x185080 (361.5GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may
take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.`

Comment: Data is 68 x 185080 single

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118549/discussion-between-willpower2727-and-dede).